# How to delete a script var/tmp

Tags: 20.04, permissions, root

I get the following error while trying to delete a temp file. I can't change the permissions because apparently I'm not the owner.Any assistance on how to go about it will greatly be appreciated

**There was an error deleting the file "battery-status-1.sh.swl"
Error removing file /var/tmp/battery-status-1.sh.swl: Operation not permitted**

Comment: (1) Why are you trying to delete this file? (2) What is the exact command you ran to try to delete it?

Comment: I was creating a scriptin the tmp folder and it didn't go as expected. I've tried opening the tmp folder in terminal and then ran;  rm -rf *

Comment: No don't do that. If you want to delete that file, `sudo rm someFile` should work fine. One thing to know... some systems will sometimes clean up the tmp folders. So I suggest not storing your files there. Your home directory, or better yet Git, is a better option.

Comment: @cocomac `/var/tmp` is supposed to be preserved between reboots according to [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: @doneal24 Yes. But [this Unix SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30504/495409) notes that "Some systems also clean `/var/tmp`, but less often."

Comment: @cocomac, Thanks bro. It worked. I cant thank you enough